# My Syntax Error Calculation in SharePoint List is not worked T_T

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, syntax, validation-error

I have so so BIG problem!!

So, I'm trying to generate the verdict syntax calculation, but it shows the wrong answer.
Please help me T_T.

[image]

The pictures show the filled value from 2 columns before. In the last column, I tried to write the formula: **IF([%LIN @150mA]<="10%", "PASS", "NOT PASS")** and it didn't work

[image]

The data type column of [%LIN @150mA] shows as the picture below.
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the type of `[%LIN @150mA]` column? Can you share the screenshot of column settings for this column as well?

Comment: It's calculated (calculation based on other columns) and the data type returned is number. I have added a screenshot on the top already, thank you.

Comment: Try using `IF([%LIN @150mA]<=10, "PASS", "NOT PASS") ` or `IF([%LIN @150mA]<=10%, "PASS", "NOT PASS")`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I tried already, but it didn't work again.
Can I ask you something? If I calculate from the input number, also use the text function to format like "0.00", and select datatype to number. What is the final type after calculation, is it a number??

Comment: Instead of using text() function to format it, use "Show as percentage" check box to `%` after the calculated number.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the data type column of [%LIN @150mA] according to the following figure:
[image]

The data type column of [VD %LIN @150mA] Using this formula: `IF([%LIN @150mA]<=10%, "PASS", "NOT PASS")`

Numeric percentages do not require double quotes.

Here is my test, ignoring my test data, this worked during my test period:
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.